# Sharing with facebook using Sharekit giving Application Response Error

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter, sharekit

I am using share kit to integrate facebook and twitter in iphone application. I want to share text message to Facebook and twitter. On facebook I am getting "Application Response Error The post's action links must be valid URLs. You can see this because you are one of the developer of the app.

In case twitter I am getting message in Alert "Authorize Error Your SHKTwitter config is incorrect.You must set your application type to browser and define a callback url. See SHKConfig.h for more details".

and No message is shared on both facebook and twitter.

Comment: have u added API Key and secret for Twitter and facebook..???

Comment: Yes, I have added APIkey and secrete key.

Comment: can you post some code.. where you are getting error

Comment: I am not getting error in code. I can properly login to Facebook and twitter both but It is not sharing the text and displaying above given messages.

Comment: Did you ever solve the facebook error? I cant find an answer anywhere

Answer (score 1):

When you register your application at twitter developer site .. chosse your application type to browser not client and also provide callbackurl.. like this http://example.com you can provide your company url or what u want.

This error

> set your application type to browser and define a callback url.

is because of application setting